# Cannot draw checkbox in QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have a `QStyledItemDelegate` derived object for a `QTableView` derived view.  I further delegate the painting and editor creation depending on the model index data type.  For `bool`s I wanted to represent the state via a checkbox - but the check box never appears.

Here is the base delegate paint function:

```
void Sy_QtPropertyDelegate::paint( QPainter* painter,
                                   const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                                   const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    painter->save();

    if ( index.column() == 0 ) {
        ...
    } else {
        QVariant var = index.data();
        bool modified = index.data( Sy_QtPropertyModel::ModifiedRole ).toBool();

        //  If the data type is one of our delegates, then push the work onto
        //  that.
        auto it = delegateMap_.find( var.type() );
        if ( it != delegateMap_.end() ) {
            ( *it )->paint( painter, option, index );
        } else if ( var.type() != QVariant::UserType ) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    painter->restore();
}
```

And the `bool` sub delegate paint function:

```
void Sy_boolPD::paint( QPainter* painter,
                       const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                       const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    painter->save();

    bool checked  = index.data().toBool();
    bool modified = index.data( Sy_QtPropertyModel::ModifiedRole ).toBool();

    QStyle* style = Sy_application::style();
    if ( modified ) {
        QStyleOptionViewItemV4 bgOpt( option );
        bgOpt.backgroundBrush = QBrush( Sy_QtPropertyDelegate::ModifiedColour );
        style->drawControl( QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &bgOpt, painter );
    }

    QStyleOption butOpt( option );
    butOpt.state = QStyle::State_Enabled;
    butOpt.state |= checked ? QStyle::State_On : QStyle::State_Off;
    style->drawControl( QStyle::CE_CheckBox, &butOpt, painter );

    painter->restore();
}
```

If I force `modified` to be true, the background is colour of the table is appropriately changed, and `cout`ing `butOpt`'s `rect` and `state` members show that they are correct - but no check box is shown!  Setting `QStyle::CE_CheckBox` to any other type also causes nothing to render.

I've worked with Qt's MVC framework a lot, but I cannot see where I have gone wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was look in the source code...

```
case CE_CheckBox:
    if (const QStyleOptionButton *btn = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionButton *>(option)) {
    ...
    }
```

The `QStyleOption` I pass to the method is cast to the type specific for drawing the control, `CE_CheckBox` requires a `QStyleOptionButton`, and if the cast fails the drawing operation silently skips.