# QTreeView custom column

Tags: c++, qt

I need show files from `QFileSystemModel` in `QTreeView` and customize that tree to show one more column with `QCheckBox`, so user can pick 0..N files from that `QTreeView`.
I read doc from Qt to understand model/view architecture and i am now in my code at point, where i have custom delegate `CustomItemDelegate`for specific column, but actually i don't know how to create `QCheckBox` in paint method of my custom delegate (to be more specific i know how, but this is 99% bad way).

**customitemdelegate.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMITEMDELEGATE_H
#define CUSTOMITEMDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class CustomItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
    void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const;

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // CUSTOMITEMDELEGATE_H
```

**customitemdelegate.cpp**

```
#include "customitemdelegate.h"
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTreeView>

using namespace std;

CustomItemDelegate::CustomItemDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

 void CustomItemDelegate::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const {

     ((QTreeView *)parent())->setIndexWidget(index, new QCheckBox());

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a `QCheckbox`, you *paint* one using the current style.  Look at the [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qstyle.html) regarding `QStyle`, specifically for `drawControl(..)`.  There's also a customised example I wrote for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235273/cannot-draw-checkbox-in-qstyleditemdelegate) on SO which you can get an idea from.

Mouse handling has to be handled by the view (because the control doesn't actually exist), and for most styles that will include mouse-over updating.

It is a bit of a pain (things may have gotten easier in v5.0+, I last did this in v4.8), but it's well worth it.  Creating 'real' `QCheckBox`s is inefficient (in your example it will cause a *massive* memory leak), and becomes noticeably slow for large datasets.  Whereas painting a 'fake' one only when required (i.e. visible) is very fast.